# Images downloading and declaring the supported file types in iOS

Tags: ios, file, plist, jpeg

My app downloads some image files by using `NSURLConnection` and stores them into `Documents` directory as `jpeg`, such as a user profile picture. Those images are intended to be shown to the user by means of the app's user interface, they are not intended to be saved anywhere else or exported, nor shared, just to be displayed within the app. And the app is neither intended to open files in any other way. Must I declare the `jpeg` file type in the `Info.plist`?

Thanks

Comment: No you are not supposed to specify it `Info.plist`.You need to specify  if your app is intended to open any format files such as `pdf,xls,etc` from other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to add the file type to Info.plist if your app just uses it, but only, eventually, if it manages that type (i.e. for editing).

Comment: I was reading the `Declaring Your App's Supported Document Types` section in [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). I needed to make sure that this is not necessary to be done if you're simply showing the images you're downloading...

Comment: I see what you mean. No, you don't need to add that to the Info.plist if your app uses that file type, but only, eventually, if it manages that type (i.e. for editing).